# Getting blur stroked while drawing in Cglayer

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, cglayer

I am working with a drawing app where I draw inside CGlayers and then draw on grahics context, but I drawing is getting blurred.

Here is my code

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();//Get a reference to current context(The context to draw)
             NSLog(@"Size1%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));

            if(self.currentDrawingLayer == nil)
            {
                self.currentDrawingLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, self.bounds.size, NULL);
            }


            CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(m_previousPoint1, m_previousPoint2);
            CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(m_currentPoint, m_previousPoint1);


            CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(self.currentDrawingLayer);
           // UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size,YES,0.0);

            CGContextSetLineCap(layerContext, kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(layerContext, kCGBlendModeNormal);
            CGContextSetLineJoin(layerContext, kCGLineJoinRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(layerContext, self.lineWidth);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(layerContext, self.lineColor.CGColor);
            CGContextSetShouldAntialias(layerContext, YES);
            CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(layerContext, YES);
            CGContextSetAlpha(layerContext, self.lineAlpha);
            CGContextSetFlatness(layerContext, 1.0f);
            CGContextBeginPath(layerContext);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(layerContext, mid1.x, mid1.y);//Position the current point
            CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(layerContext, m_previousPoint1.x, m_previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(layerContext);//paints(fills) the line along the current path.

            CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, self.bounds, self.currentDrawingLayer);
}
```

I get blurr strokes with this code, according to docs, whenever we create the CGlayer with graphicsContext, they say that it will provide the resolution of the device, but then why I am getting blur lines.

Here is the image of blur lines
[image]

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute this in your code where you create your CGLayer:

```
if(self.currentDrawingLayer == nil)
{
    CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width * scale, self.bounds.size.height * scale);
    CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, bounds.size, NULL);
    CGContextRef layerContext = CGLayerGetContext(layer);
    CGContextScaleCTM(layerContext, scale, scale);
    self.currentDrawingLayer = layer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Can you please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027788/drawing-multiple-images-with-different-size-on-cglayer

Comment: Hello @Gavin, please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438586/undo-redo-for-drawing-in-ios I need your help

Comment: Hello @Gavin please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21906687/getting-pixelated-strokes-while-drawing-uibezeirpath-in-cglayer

Comment: Hello @Gavin, what you have to say ?

Comment: Hello @Gavin, please help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935064/undo-with-multitouch-drawing-in-ios